# How to duplicate rows based on cell value in R?

Tags: r, duplicates, row

For instance, in the table below, in column 2, I have three separate links, separated by semicolons and %20, so I want to duplicate the row three times, then I want to make sure each row only contains 1 link so that all three links are shown in three separate rows, keeping all other values the same. The actual dataset contains between 1 and 5 links per row in that column.

[image]

Comment: There is no table example in your post

Answer (score 0):

Considering `df` your dataframe with 2 columns `c1` and `c2` :

```
df=data.frame(c1=c("Hello world","Blabla"),c2=c("https://youtube.com;%20https://stack.com;%20discord.com","https://youtube.com;%20https://stack.com;%20discord.com;%20https://stackoverflow.com"))
```

The `separate_rows()` function is exactly dedicated to separate the values and place each one in a new row with corresponding value :

```
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df, c2, sep=";%20")

# A tibble: 7 × 2
  c1          c2                       
  <chr>       <chr>                    
1 Hello world https://youtube.com      
2 Hello world https://stack.com        
3 Hello world discord.com              
4 Blabla      https://youtube.com      
5 Blabla      https://stack.com        
6 Blabla      discord.com              
7 Blabla      https://stackoverflow.com
```